# Restcomm handle messages from sip phone

Tags: telecommunication, restcomm

we are going to configure our restcomm instance to handle sms messages.
But we would like to test this functionality with sip chat messages during development

is it possible to send message from sip phone to the specific to the registered sip number?

do we have another way "to send" sms to sip number w/o real sms sending?
maybe some resp api can help us with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linphone or other SIP client to send/receive SMS from/to RestComm.

To send SMS from RestComm:

- design SMS application in RVD and assign **sms enabled DID** to it
- in your SMS application, in "To" section, enter the SIP address to which you want to send SMS (e.g.: sip:user@sip.linphone.org)
- register in your SIP client
- in your sip client enter the number bound to your SMS application (SMS applications must use SMS enabled DIDs in order to send/receive SMS)
- call the number associated with your application
- user@sip.linphone.org should have received SMS

Here you are useful post from the RestComm docs page on how to send SMS to SIP phone http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-send-sms-to-a-sip-phone/

If you want to send SMS from SIP client to RestComm application you can do the following:

- register in your SIP client
- enter the SIP number registered in Restcomm and associated with SMS application
- right-click on the app number and choose to send text message
- enter your message and click on the Send button

To check if the SMS has been received from Restcomm in Admin UI go to **Logs -> Messages**

Here is how log for received message from SIP client (Linphone in this case) looks like:

[image]

Here you are an example of sending SMS using the API:

```html
curl -X POST http://ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf:MyPassword@192.168.1.3:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/SMS/Messages -d "To=7777" -d "From=6666" -d "Body=This is a SMS Restcomm test"   

    <RestcommResponse>
    <SMSMessage>
    <Sid>SMde6b385aaba548b889a678a8357cea7f</Sid>
    <DateCreated>Thu, 6 Aug 2015 07:55:25 -0600</DateCreated>
    <DateUpdated>Thu, 6 Aug 2015 07:55:25 -0600</DateUpdated>
    <DateSent/>
    <AccountSid>ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf</AccountSid>
    <From>6666</From>
    <To>7777</To>
    <Body>This is a SMS Restcomm test</Body>
    <Status>sending</Status>
    <Direction>outbound-api</Direction>
    <Price>0</Price>
    <PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>
    <ApiVersion>2012-04-24</ApiVersion>
    <Uri>/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/SMS/Messages/SMde6b385aaba548b889a678a8357cea7f</Uri>
  </SMSMessage>
</RestcommResponse>[user@localhost configuration]$
```

The "To" must be a number registered with Restcomm listening to an SMS application